# How to input custom lines to tesseract for OCR?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I want to know if there is a way to input custom line bounding boxes to `tesseract` for OCR. I didn't find documentation for line finding.

Assuming that I have a list where each element consists of list of bounding box coordinates, what is the efficient way to do this ?

The custom text lines are used here, because the input has skews in multiple directions.

Answer (score 0):

Write the left, top, width, height and a remark (e.g. 1st line etc.) in a file, one line in the file per text line to specify. This file must have the same name as you image file, but with the extension `uzn` (e.g. for `myImage.tif` name it `myImage.uzn`) and must reside in the same directory as the image file. Then specify **single column mode** `-psm 4`.

The uzn file format specification can be found [here](https://github.com/OpenGreekAndLatin/greek-dev/wiki/uzn-format).

Comment: Can the rectangles be skewed (rotated) for this ? How does it know the rotation without specifying it ?

Comment: no, bounding boxes can't be rotated, the opposite edge is calculated as left + width and top + height, respectively.

Comment: the only workaround I can think of in this case, where you have (a small number) of different text rotation angles, is to do the OCR in multiple passes, each pass for one angle on the accordingly rotated image file (and you'll have to rotate the bounding box coordinates as well). Output can be done in the hocr format along with the coordinates to assemble all the individual results. All in all not very convenient though.